# custom sound duration on IOS with flutter_local_notification

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-local-notification

I am using flutter_local_notification version 16.2.0 for a flutter app. I can play custom sounds on both Android and IOS. For IOS, I have stored custom sound clips in the ios/Runner folder in .caf and .aiff format. The duration of the sound file is between 20 - 30 seconds.

Custom sounds plays at the scheduled time - in both cases, when the app is in the foreground or background. However, it only plays the first 7-8 seconds.

Is there are setting or limit in flutter_local_notification that restricts the custom sound to play for only 7-8 seconds?
Can you please help me figure out what I am missing?